# How to stop controller looking for a video id if not present

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in my events show controller:

```
  def show
    @event = Event.find_by_name(params[:id])
    if request.path != event_path(@event)
      redirect_to @event, status: :moved_permanently
    end
    if @event.videos.present?
      @video = @event.videos.find(params[:video]) || @event.videos.first
      if :video_id.present? && current_user && @video.premium?
        @order = Order.new(user_id: current_user.id, video_id: @video.id, price: @video.price)    
      elsif :event_id.present? && current_user && @event.premium?
        @order = Order.new(user_id: current_user.id, event_id: @event.id, price: @event.price)    
      end
    end
    @user = User.new
  end
```

This line:

```
      @video = @event.videos.find(params[:video]) || @event.videos.first
```

Should find the video if it has been passed on ID into the params, such as by this link:

```
event_path(video.event.name, video: video)
```

When a video is passed into the params, the app works fine and the correct video is shown in the correct event.

However when a video ID isn't passed into the params, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find Video without an ID
```

I thought that the || operator would skip past the @event.videos.find(params[:video] part and just pick the first videos associated with the event to display, but clearly this is no longer happening, and I think the problem has been introduced since adding friendly_id to videos, although I can't say for sure.

Videos belong to Events, and an Event has many Videos.

Can anyone help show me how I can have @video show the clicked video when the params are passed into it, and the first video belonging to the event if there are no params passed?

Comment: I think there is a bug in your code, described it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` method throws an exception if there isn't record with such id (nil in your case). Try this line:

```
@video = @event.videos.find_by_id(params[:video]) || @event.videos.first
```

There `find_by_id` method will return nil if params[:video] is blank and `@event.videos.first` will be returned.

Also, I think there is a bug in your code: look at second line (`Event.find_by_name(params[:id])`). If it returns nil then later `@event.videos.present?` throws an exception when calling `videos` method on nil.

Comment: Fantastic thanks, did the trick.  Will check out the additional bug you've spotted too.

Answer (score 1):

ternary condition is what you need..

```
@video = params[:video].present?  ? @event.videos.find(params[:video]) : @event.videos.first
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if params[:video].nil?
    @video = @event.videos.first
else
   @video = @event.videos.find(params[:video])
end
```